# Make changing text on loop in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

what i'm trying to do seems pretty simple. keyword seems. haha.

I'm trying to make text that changes back and forth between two languages. Kind of like a GIF type animation (tried that didn't like how it looked) I know flash would be the better option but I don't have those capabilities so i've turned to javascript- but my experience there isn't too great either. here's my HTML

```
<div id="welcomediv">
<h1 class="welcome" id="welcome">Welcome-Select your language</h1>
<h1 class="welcome" id="bienvenido">Bienvenido-Elegí tu idioma</h1>
</div>
```

Then I thought I could take that along with the following CSS

```
.welcome
{
font-size:18px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:Century Gothic;
color:White;
margin-top:5px;
margin-bottom:30px;
position:relative;
}

#welcomediv
{
display:block;
position:relative;
top:45%;
height:30px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

I did that thinking that I could use jquery to move the elements up and down and then they'd go out of view and get what i'm looking for. I want it to go up and out as the other one is sliding back into place. I achieved that. But just couldn't make it loop.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#welcome").delay(3000).animate({ bottom: '30px' }, 1000);
    $("#bienvenido").delay(3000).animate({ bottom: '45px' }, 1000);
    });
```

This is how I did it.

Now I know this probably isn't the best way to go about this so any and all help is greatly appreciated!! How would I simply make it loop? Or should I change it up totally?

Comment: Maybe you should look at these links. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_lang.asp Of course, that won't help your animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval` for this:

```
var showingWelcome = true;
setInterval(function() {
  if (showingWelcome) {
    $("#welcome").animate({ bottom: '30px' }, 1000);
    $("#bienvenido").animate({ bottom: '45px' }, 1000);
    showingWelcome = false;
  }
  else {
    $("#welcome").animate({ bottom: '0px' }, 1000);
    $("#bienvenido").animate({ bottom: '0px' }, 1000);
    showingWelcome = true;
  }
}, 3000);
```

Here's a JSBin http://jsbin.com/xoziquze/1/edit?html,css,js,output that shows it working.

By the way, in my opinion JavaScript is perfectly fine for this and Flash would be overkill.

Comment: Thanks!!  That worked perfectly.  I never would've been able to come up with that on my own.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're looking to do is animate the text back and forth you may want to consider using a CSS [keyframe animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes), like so:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8mRc3/1/)**

```
.welcome {
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Century Gothic;
    color:red;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    position:relative;
    animation: yourAnim 3s infinite alternate; /* name, duration, number of iterations, direction */
}

@keyframes yourAnim {
    0%{bottom: 0px;}
    25%{bottom: 0px;}
    50%{bottom: 55px}
    100%{bottom: 55px;}
}
```

Note browser prefixes omitted for brevity.